# Idempotent linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_5\rightarrow P_5$ be a linear map such that $T^2=T$ and $rankT=3$. What is $T$?

$P_5$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most 5

I'm really not sure how to proceed with this any hints?

Comment: There are, presumably _many_ such $T$. Are you supposed to find a specific one, or just say "$T$ is a projection" and be done? And what is $P_5$?

Comment: What exactly is $P_5$?

Comment: @Arthur I must find one

Comment: @D.Brogan set of polynomials of degree at most 5

Answer (score 0):

$T$ could be, for example, the transformation setting $x^3=x^4=x^5=0$, not in the substitution sense, but in the linear algebra sense. Thus $T(1)=1$, $T(x)=x$, $T(x^2)=x^2$, $T(x^3)=T(x^4)=T(x^5)=0$.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the process of finding the particular map, please?

Comment: @topologicalmagician It helps to know that if $T^2=T$, then $T$ is a projection onto some subspace, just like $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$. Since you need it to be three dimensions, I'm actually wrong and $x^3$ needs to go to zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** The conditions $T^2=T$ and $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Im}T=3$ imply that $T$ is a projection onto a 3-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 5}$. There are many examples.